# My test site only works in Safari and Chrome no IE no Firefox, Please Help

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari

to any code guru, here is my test site http://www.chalesphotography.com/site/home.html
it's not a finis site i'm just working on it, the problem is at this point is not working in any version of IE or Firefox.
Please Help
Thank You in advance

Comment: Looks like the Flash video isn't loading. Is the library you're using cross-browser? What do you do for people who don't have Flash?

Comment: No, the flash video is definitely loading.  I checked it with firebug.  Also, he's using SWFObject to load the flash, which is definitely cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of the html to 100%.

```
html {
   height : 100%;
}
```

Edit:
Is this what you tried to do in your css by using `html body {...}`?  If so, you need to add a comma between "html" and "body" to make the css rules apply to both html and body.  Otherwise, the browser applies the rules to element "body" which is a descendent of element "html".

This will create ugly scrollbars, but you can remove them with

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: @BernzSed thank you very much, i try your suggestion an now its working in all browser. at least the flash animation is showing @100%. The new problem is the nav_bar and logo disappear, only are visible in safari for Mac. thanks againg.

Comment: i'm sorry the flash movie works in safari for mac and win and in firefox, onli showing the nav_bar and logo in safari for mac. now in IE i see the nav_bar and the logo but no the movie. I'm lost.

Comment: You have the size of the flash movie set to 100% height and width and overflow is hidden to remove the scroll bars. That means anything below the flash - in this case your navigation, is going to fall outside the display area. You will have to adjust the height of the flash move to all for the navigation to work in all browsers.

Comment: @Brent Friar, thanks for your time, when you said adjust the height of the flash to all means change 100% to all?

Comment: UPDATE: in IE8 i'm able to see the flash animation but not the nav_bar or the logo, but if i click on compatibility view i see the nav_bar and logo but not the movie. now i need help there is definetly something wrong.

Comment: It looks like you have it worked out now, the nav bar is now positioned absolutely so that it shows up. You shouldn't have to change the size of the flash movie now.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your `z-index to 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked it with the w3 validator? have you used firebug, and the built-in firefox error console?

Comment: i validate both the HTML and the CSS

Comment: OK, how about Firebug or the error console? those don't help?